# How to detect whether the user is doing a login or signup submit in firebase auth?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-analytics

I found this blog that explains a pretty neat way to organize Sign ups and logins for google analytics data.

[Blog](https://www.charlesfarina.com/login-and-signup-naming-conventions-for-google-analytics/)

I would like to implement this design with my firebase web app, but am having difficulty finding a **Submit** indicator to hook on to and find out whether the user is Signing Up with a provider or doing a Login in e.g.

```
firebase.Auth().signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider())
```

I can only find out after the submit when the promise returns but **I don't know for certain** if the promise will or will not always return to determine whether the user singing in was trying to signup or not. (If there is a **guaranteed** resolve or reject on the promise I can also do login/signup-submit event to google analytics)

- Does the auth promise have a timeout to guarantee that the promise gets rejected? (with the provider email sent back in error?).
- Does firebase have any other events that can give me the email on sumbit? (Note: Using Google provider lets the user choose the email so I need to know after the user makes the choice in the popup).

With the above two points, I don't mind sending the email to the backend-cloud-functions and having the admin check if the user existed or not for a sign-up/login determination. But if there is an easier solution to do this in the client I'm also open to suggestions.